# SASS - Grupo de cores para re-uso

Tags: css, css3, sass

estou iniciando no SASS, e estou com um probleminha que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho um grupo de cores, que serão utilizados em várias sessões do meu site.

Basicamente, tenho uma estrutura assim:

```
<section id="lista-noticias" class="regioes">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="data">SÁBADO, 17/05/2017, 20:07</span>
        <h5 class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, quam dolore nemo itaque possimus? Dolore, doloribus corporis, voluptatibus, quasi necessitatibus hic quo quia rem, asperiores libero soluta. Eveniet, optio aspernatur.</h5>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Tenho minha lista de cores assim:

```
$cor-regioes: #b71c1c;
$cor-esporte: #1b5e20;
$cor-saude: #f57f17;
$cor-arte: #0d47a1;
```

O que gostaria de "automatizar" é que quando eu colocar a `class` "regioes", os elementos internos daquela `section` pegariam as cores da minha variavel `cor-regioes`, como o `a:hover`, `span`, etc.

Eu tentei assim:

```
$cor-esporte: #1b5e20;
$cor-vida: #f57f17;
$cor-regioes: #b71c1c;

$cores: $cor-esporte, $cor-vida, $cor-regioes;

@mixin cor-elementos($cor) {
  a:hover, span.data {
    color: $cor
  }
}

@each $cor in $cores {
  section.#{$cor} {
    @include cor-elementos($cor);
  }
}
```

Porém, na section, ele pega como class, a cor em HEXADECIMAL,e não funciona.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

Como sugestão de implementação, utilize a função [map-get()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method), exemplo:

```
$cores: ('cor-esporte' : #1b5e20,  'cor-vida': #f57f17, 'cor-regioes': #b71c1c );
$classes: cor-esporte cor-vida cor-regioes;

@mixin cor-elementos($cor) {
  a:hover, span.data {
    color: map-get($cores, '#{$cor}');
  }
}

@each $classe in $classes {
  section.#{$classe} {
    @include cor-elementos($classe);
  }
}
```

Comment: Boa... vlw pela dica.. vou testar aqui também!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui!!

Pra quem quiser, fica o codigo abaixo. Pode ser que há alguma outra forma de fazer, mas essa que fiz, já serviu para mim!

```
$cor-regioes: #FFCC00;
$cor-esporte: #CC0000;
$cor-vida: #CCBBCC;

@mixin config-icon-colors($colors...) {
  @each $i in $colors {

      .#{nth($i, 1)}{
        color: nth($i, 2);

        .data {
          color: nth($i, 2);
        }
        a:hover {
          h5 {
            color: nth($i, 2);
          }
        }
      }
   }
}

@include config-icon-colors(
'regioes' $cor-regioes,
'esporte' $cor-esporte,
'vida' $cor-vida);
```